# Make a table row non clickable using HTML

Tags: html

I have a table that has 3 rows.

```
<a href="www.google.com">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Non Clickable</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</a>
```

I want to make the 3rd row non clickable using HTML. Is it possible?

I do not wish to apply anchor tag inside each individual `<td>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to make text unclickable? What's the real goal?

Comment: How do think that this can be done when you added the whole table inside `a` tag ?

Comment: Having *an entire table* be a link is pretty strange to begin with.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean make the 3rd table row non-clickable using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking: "Can I have some text inside an anchor tag be clickable and other text not clickable?" To which the answer is, "No, that's not how HTML works." By declaring an `<a href="foo.html">...</a>` tag, you're declaring that the entire content of that tag should be linked to `foo.html`.

It looks like you're going to have to put the links inside the table (and, really, you should have a link inside each `<td>`, annoying as that can be).